# Is the defintion given of a Hasse diagram correct?

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, relations, order-theory

I am currently reading *Proofs: A Long Form Mathematics Textbook* written by Jay Cummings, and am on the section about Partial Orders. When discussing how to visualize a POSET he defines a Hasse diagram as follows:

[image]
Also note I believe the author intended to say A = powerset({1,2,3})

I am confused as if you look at the diagram he has drawn it doesn't match the definition he gives. The sets {1,3} and {2} are incomparable with inclusion so according to his rules should be draw on the same vertical level, but are drawn on different vertical levels in the diagram. Same thing with {1,2} and {3}.

When I looked online every definition of Hasse diagrams I found didn't make any mention to drawing incomparable elements on the same vertical level. They only mentioned how if an element **a** covers an element **b**(meaning **a**≤**b** and there is no **c** for which **a**≤**c**<**b**) then **a** is placed below **b**, and a line is draw from **a** to **b**.

My current guess is that the author included an incorrect definition of a Hasse diagram. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: They can't be "on the same vertical level". If that were so, then $\{2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ would be at the same level, as you point out, but also $\{1,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$, for the same reason, whence $\{2\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ would be at the same level, which clearly could not happen, since $\{2\} \subset \{1,2\}$. I can't make any sense of that expression. Maybe the author was trying to give a more intuitive approach but overlooked some details?